# Prove Triangle Inequality for Two Special Cases

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am reading "Understanding Analysis" - it is a great book. However, I lack a solutions manual and some of these answers are difficult to find. It has been a while since I've written proofs and I'm wondering if these proofs are sufficient for the problem, or I can do better:

The problem states:

> Use the triangle inequality to establish the inequalities:
>
> (a) $|a - b| \le |a| + |b|$
>
> (b) $||a| - |b|| \le |a - b|$

Starting with (a):

Note that $|a - b| = |a + (-b)|$

so $|a + (-b)| \le |a| + |-b|$ by the definition of the *Triangle Inequality*.

So $|a + (-b)| \le a + b$ by applying the rules of the absolute value.

By definition $|a + b| \le a + b$

which surely means $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$ by the rules of the absolute value.

and since we have shown $|a + (-b)| \le a + b$, $|a + b| \le a + b$ and, $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$

Then it must the be case where $|a - b| \le |a| + |b|$

---

For (b) it seems we can proceed directly:

$||a| - |b|| = |a - b|$ by the definition of the absolute value.

Then it must be the case that $|a - b| \le |a - b|$

and so $||a| - |b|| \le |a - b|$

---

I hope I did these correctly. It would be very helpful if I could be provided the correct answer if I am wrong - and methods to write cleaner proofs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### (a) Prove $|a - b| \le |a| + |b|$

We know that $|x|+|y| \ge |x+y|$

$$\text{Let $x=a$ and let $y=-b$. Substituting we get}$$

\begin{align}
   |x|+|y| &\ge |x+y| \\
   |a| + |-b| &\ge |a + (-b)| \\
   |a| + |b| &\ge |a-b| \\
   |a-b| &\le |a| + |b|
\end{align}

### (b) Prove $||a| - |b|| \le |a - b|$

$$\text{Let $x=a$ and $y=b-a$.}$$
\begin{align}
   |x|+|y| &\ge |x+y| \\
   |a| + |b-a| &\ge |b| \\
   |a| + |a-b| &\ge |b| \\
   |b| &\le |a| + |a-b| \\
   -|a-b| &\le |a| - |b| \tag{1.} 
\end{align}

$$\text{Next, let $x=b$ and $y=a-b$.}$$
\begin{align}
   |x|+|y| &\ge |x+y| \\
   |b| + |a-b| &\ge |a| \\
   |a| &\le |b| + |a-b| \\
   |a| - |b| &\le |a-b|  \tag{2.}
\end{align}

$$\text{From $(1.)$ and $(2.)$, we get}$$
\begin{align}
      -|a-b| \le |a| - |b| \le |a-b| \\
      ||a| - |b|| \le |a - b| 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If you have the already proven the standard form of the triangle inequality.

$|a+b| \le  |a|+|b|$

then you can say.

$|a-b| = |a+(-b)| \le |a|+|-b| = |a|+|b|$

But you didn't stop there.  And, what you do say after that is incorrect.  You say "$|a+b| \le a+b$" when, in fact, $|a+b| \ge a+b$

As for the second one, I am not following your logic.  Here is what I might say.

$||a|-|b|| = ||(a-b)+b| - |b|| \le ||a-b| + |b| - |b|| = |a-b|$

If you don't have the the proof of the standard form in your back pocket, then square both sides, or brute force the cases:

$a\ge 0$ and $b\ge 0, a<0$ and $b\ge 0, a\ge 0$ and $b< 0, a< 0$ and $b< 0.$

Answer (score 0):

$ \lvert a+b \rvert \leq a+b$ is untrue. A counter example is $a=b=-1$. In fact, the reverse inequality is true by the triangle inequality: $ \lvert a+b \rvert \geq a+b$.

You need to use two facts for proving the first inequality:

(1) $a+(-b)=a-b$

(2) $ \lvert -b \rvert= \lvert b \rvert$

For (b), $\lvert \lvert a \rvert -\lvert b\rvert \rvert=\lvert a-b\rvert$ is untrue. A counter examples is a=1 and b=-1.

A correct reasoning would be noting $\lvert a-b \rvert=\lvert b-a \rvert$.
And $\lvert a-b \rvert +\lvert b \rvert  \geq \lvert (a-b)+b \rvert=\lvert a \rvert$ by the trinagle inequality. 
Similarly $\lvert b-a \rvert +\lvert a \rvert \geq \lvert (b-a)+a \rvert=\lvert b \rvert$
Therefore we have $\lvert a-b \rvert \geq max(\lvert a \rvert-\lvert b \rvert,\lvert b \rvert-\lvert a \rvert)=\lvert \lvert a \rvert-\lvert b \rvert \rvert$ by the definition of the absolute value.