# Using the triangle inequality to show $|a-b|\le|a|+|b|$

Tags: inequality

I'm running through Undestanding Analysis by Stephen Abbot, I'm self taught so I require the forum for verification. I am to use the triangle inequality to show that $|a-b|\le|a|+|b|$

Intuitively $|a+b-c|\le|a|+|b|+|c|$

and removing $|a|$ from both sides gives $|b-c|\le|b|+|c|$

Therefore,

$|a-b|\le|a|+|b|$

Is this correct?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\lvert a-b\rvert=\lvert a+(-b)\rvert$.

Comment: you can not just "remove" $|a|$ from both sides

Comment: Many thanks @Lorago, is it $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$, so $|a+(-b)|\le|a|+|(-b)|$, therefore $|a-b|\le|a|+|b|$?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3085309/42969

Comment: Yep exactly, you got it!

Comment: @Lorogo, many thanks!

Comment: @MartinR I did not see this answer previously, many thanks, is it possible with my reputation to close this question?